# Using MySQL many to many select statement to find relative rows

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

I try to use inner join to find relative rows.

But seems it is returning nothing. Please advise.

Basically, I have decomposed all keywords from the original page title and description of every articles. So, when I come to search I can query the keyword table.

here is a articles with keywords

-- Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE article         ( id INT, title TEXT, description TEXT );
CREATE TABLE keyword         ( id INT, keyword VARCHAR(255) );
CREATE TABLE article_keyword ( article_id INT, keyword_id INT );
```

-- Add Article 1

```
insert into article set
id = 1,
title = "my text book like a black hole",
description = "I have a text book. Any people who read it and after days they will disappear. etc...";
```

-- Add keywords for article 1

```
insert into keyword set
id = 1,
keyword = "text book";

insert into keyword set
id = 2,
keyword = "black hole";

insert into article_keyword set
article_id = 1,
keyword_id = 1;

insert into article_keyword set
article_id = 1,
keyword_id = 2;
```

-- Add ARTICLE 2

```
insert into article set
id = 2,
title = "the fact of deep space black hole",
description = "More researches are telling fake story about black holes is exists. But my alien friend tell me it is wrong ... etc";
```

-- Add keywords for article 2

```
insert into keyword set
id = 3,
keyword = "research";

insert into keyword set
id = 4,
keyword = "alien";

insert into article_keyword set
article_id = 2,
keyword_id = 2;

insert into article_keyword set
article_id = 2,
keyword_id = 3;

insert into article_keyword set
article_id = 2,
keyword_id = 4;
```

-- Finding using "text book", expected 1 articles

```
SELECT article.id, title FROM article
JOIN article_keyword ak ON ak.article_id = article.id
JOIN keyword k1         ON ak.keyword_id = k1.id
WHERE k1.keyword = "text book"
```

-- Finding using "black hole", expected 2 articles

```
SELECT article.id, title FROM article
JOIN article_keyword ak ON ak.article_id = article.id
JOIN keyword k2         ON ak.keyword_id = k2.id
WHERE k2.keyword = "black hole"
```

-- When search for a book includes all these keywords then get none.

```
SELECT article.id, title FROM article
JOIN article_keyword ak ON ak.article_id = article.id
JOIN keyword k1         ON ak.keyword_id = k1.id
JOIN keyword k2         ON ak.keyword_id = k2.id
WHERE k1.keyword = "text book"
AND   k2.keyword = "black hole";
```

Any idea mysql couldn't give me back article 1?

Anything wrong with this query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your query is wrong as the first where clause limits the join between article_keyword and keyword (k1) to the row with keyword = 1 and article_id = 1 and no row will match the second where clause for keyword 2.

If you want articles with multiple keywords you can use this query:

```
SELECT article.id, title 
FROM article
JOIN article_keyword ak ON ak.article_id = article.id
JOIN keyword k          ON ak.keyword_id = k.id
WHERE k.keyword = "text book"
OR    k.keyword = "black hole"
GROUP BY article.id, title
HAVING COUNT(keyword) = 2
```